# How can I reset sandboxed in-app purchases on iOS for testing?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, mkstorekit

I made a sandbox iTunes user, bought an item. That worked but there were some issues in my code for displaying the item. So, I want to re-buy it to test again. Problem is, I can't clear my purchases. I signed out my sandbox user, deleted the app and re-installed it, changed itunes users a few times... the item still shows up as purchased.

I'm using MKStoreKit.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. MKStoreKit saves purchased items to the keychain, which persists even if you change iTunes accounts or delete the app. Calling a quick `[[MKStoreManager sharedManager] removeAllKeychainData];` reset things.

Comment: just making things clear. this didn't reset your purchase. the next time you pressed "buy" you actually restored the purchase.

Answer (score -4):

If you have your own domain, you often get email handling for free; for example, I have a go daddy account, and I can set a mail forwarding rule for unrecognised email accounts.  This makes it very easy to create loads of test accounts without having to have a separate email account for each one.